# Append HTML into table cell using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This problem is driving me nuts. I have this HTML:

```
<div class="matchup-container">
    <div class="gamequestion">
        <strong>Who will win?</strong>
    </div>
    <table class="mg-gametableQ">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="mg-column1 start">
                    <div class="matchupDate">
                        <span class="startTime">11:00 AM</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="mg-column3 opponents  ">
                    <span>
                        <strong>
                            <a href="link">Team</a>: Win
                        </strong>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="mg-column1 start">
                    <div class="matchupDate">
                        <span class="startTime">11:00 AM</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="mg-column3 opponents   otherthings">
                    <span>
                        <strong>
                            <a href="link">Team</a>: Win
                        </strong>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I know it's a mess, but it's what I'm working with. So there's more than one `matchup-container`. I want to loop through all of them on the page, get down to the `td` with class containing `mg-column3`, and append some text to the Team: Win part. My JavaScript/jQuery is as follows:

```
$('.matchup-container').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.mg-column3').each(function () {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        var text = document.createTextNode("APPENDED TEXT");
        span.appendChild(text); 
        $(this).append(span);
    });
});
```

But that doesn't work. I know it must have to do with the ridiculous nesting of the HTML, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I've tried a bunch of different ways of finding the class with no luck. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68N7D/2/). Can anyone help?

Comment: You have tried this whilst actually including the jQuery library presumably?

Comment: Your question and fiddle don't line up, but on fiddle, add the jQuery library and add `index` to the arguments of the outer `.each()` loop and it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gpgekko/68N7D/4/

Comment: @gpgekko no sorry i had the wrong Fiddle link, look again

Comment: @aquemini If you've updated your Fiddle, you need to update the link to it, here in the question.

Comment: @gpgekko no i did almost immediately, i think you just got to the link before i finalized the edit

Comment: @aquemini Click the link in your question, it is still the one my comment was about.

Comment: @gpgekko not so for me, but it's fine, the only difference is the appended text and the text in the question.

Comment: @oGeez i have jquery.js and included it as a script in the Chrome extension this is a part of, i'm wondering if that's not the way to do it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z6b2S/1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

At first you did not include the jQuery lib in you jsfiddle.

Second: Why not use the jQuery lib to create Elements. --> Less fuzz.

This works
http://jsfiddle.net/qM9js/

```
;(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.matchup-container').each(function () {
            $('.mg-column3', this).each(function () {
                alert(2)
                $(this).append('<span>' + "APPENDED TEXT" + '</span>');
            });
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```